# Get attachment caption outside of Wordpress loop

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, global-variables

On my wordpress page, I have the following loop, which successfully outputs an attachment's caption.

```
<?php 
$the_query = new WP_Query(array( 'post_type' => 'attachment')); 
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :  $the_query->the_post();

$attachment_data = wp_prepare_attachment_for_js();
echo '<h2>'.$attachment_data['caption'].'</h2>'
;?>
```

Now, I also need to call the attachment caption outside of the loop. This is what I'm trying in functions.php:

```
function custom_info()
     {  
         global $wp_query;
         $query_id = $wp_query->post->ID;
         $attachment_data_query = wp_prepare_attachment_for_js( $query_id );

         wp_register_script( 'custom_data_info');
         $info = array(
             'data_query'   => $attachment_data_query['caption']
         );
         wp_enqueue_script( 'custom_data_info' );
         wp_localize_script('custom_data_info', 'info', $info);
    }
     if ( !is_admin() ) add_action( "wp_enqueue_scripts", "custom_info", 10 );
```

And then it would be called in the external javascript file like so:

```
return info.data_query
```

I know the `custom_info function` and javascript file are talking with each other correctly. The problem is with how I am defining `$query_id`

**EDIT: Almost fixed.** The problem was that I didn't include a `foreach` statement, and so the first item in the loop was being repeated over and over again.

I've adjusted below, but for some reason, now the array is empty upon output of `info.data_query`...

```
function custom_info(){  
     global $wp_query;
     wp_register_script( 'custom_data_info');

     $info = array('data_query' => array());

     foreach ( $wp_query->posts as $query_id) {
        $attachment_data_query = wp_prepare_attachment_for_js( $query_id );
        $info['data_query'][$query_id] = $attachment_data_query['caption'];

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure $wp_query will return the correct post ID? In my experience, it's better to use global $post instead. Pass that into wp_prepare_attachment_js() instead:

```
global $post;
$post_id = $post->ID;
$attachment_data_query = wp_prepare_attachment_for_js( $post_id );
```

Comment: Thanks, I've also tried that. It works on my search and date pages, but not on pages where there is a specific query. `(ex: $the_query = new WP_Query(array( _array_of_things_ )); `

Comment: Following up on this, the above function works on my search and date pages, BUT it gives all the attachments the same caption (the first item in the loop).

Comment: Edit above, if it helps.